# Check architecture of remote computer and use as conditional in batch file

Tags: windows, cmd

Since our security policy disables the running of powershell scripts, I have to use batch files.

My goal is to have a batch file on my local computer that accepts 1 argument (remote hostname).

The batch file will check the architecture of the remote computer (x64 or x86) and execute 2 differnet sets of commands based on what it returns.

Pseudo code (run locally):

```
IF (remote_computer == x86) (
    commands to be run for x86 remote host

)
IF (remote_computer == x64) (
    commands to be run for x64 remote host
)
```

How would I do this?

I can use psexec to execute single commands on the remote machine, but I can't execute scripts.  So I could get the architecture using powershell.

Comment: For PowerShell, remotely run the following: `if ([environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) { 'run x64 code' } else { 'run x86 code'}`

Comment: Take a look at [How-to: Detecting 64 bit vs 32 bit](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-64bit.html)…

Answer (score 0):

There's [registry value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details?redirectedfrom=MSDN) of `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`. Query it via `reg`, search the results with `find` and if `%errorlevel%` is zero, it was 64-bit system.

Or, test if there's `\\remotepc\c$\program files (x86)`, that should be present only on 64-bit systems.

Then there's WMI, [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) contains OSArchitecture attribute.

Comment: I could create a directory named `Program Files (x86)` if I so wish, regardless of the architecture of my Operating System. Also the environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`, does not in isolation return the Operating System's architecture. If the value returned is `x86` and the command is being run in 32-bit `cmd.exe` process, then it may still be a 64-bit OS. You would need to also take account of the value of `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432`, which, if defined means the OS is 64-bit.

Comment: @Compo Sure, one can try and confuse attempts to detect OS bitness. Got any idea how to confuse WMI? Nothing save common sense (and that might not be the case in hostile networks) prevents changing environment variables to, say, BANANAS!

Comment: I'd have suggested WMI, as the most appropriate methodology in this case, because, I'd expect it would be simpler to connect to each 'hostname' using it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-CimInstance` for this:

```
if (((Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $remoteHost).OSArchitecture -replace '\D+') -eq '64') {
    # commands to be run for 64 bit remote host
}
else {
    # commands to be run for 32 bit remote host
}
```

Comment: Needs to be cmd, not powershell.  Security policies don't allow powershell scripts.

Comment: @cclloyd I see you removed the `PowerShell` tag now. Just curious.. you are allowed to run batch scripts, but PowerShell is blocked? Weird..